# extract multidimensional dictionary to list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a multidimensional dictionary like so:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(mult_dict, width = -1)
{'lvl0': {0: {'lvl1': {0: {'lvl2': '123'},
                       1: {'lvl2': '456'}}},
          1: {'lvl1': {0: {'lvl2': '789'},
                       1: {'lvl2': '444'}}}}}
```

and I want to convert it to a list like so:

```
['123', '456', '789', '444']
```

I can do it with for loops, but I'd rather do it on one line using python's list comprehensions. I think it will be something like this, but obviously this doesn't work:

```
[lvl2 for lvl2 in lvl1 for lvl1 in lvl0 for lvl0 in mult_dict]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the dictionary values:

```
[v for lvl0 in mult_dict.itervalues() 
   for lvl1 in lvl0.itervalues() 
   for lvl2 in lvl1.itervalues()
   for lvl3 in lvl2.itervalues()
   for v in lvl3.itervalues()]
```

Remember to list your `for` loops from left to right as you'd nest them with regular `for` loops.

With this kind of deep structure, perhaps it's best to use a recursive generator:

```
def flatten_dicts(d):
    for v in d.itervalues():
        try:
            for n in flatten_dicts(v):
                yield n
        except AttributeError:
            yield v
```

Demo:

```
>>> mult_dict = {'lvl0': {0: {'lvl1': {0: {'lvl2': '123'},
...                        1: {'lvl2': '456'}}},
...           1: {'lvl1': {0: {'lvl2': '789'},
...                        1: {'lvl2': '444'}}}}}
>>> [v for lvl0 in mult_dict.itervalues() 
...    for lvl1 in lvl0.itervalues() 
...    for lvl2 in lvl1.itervalues()
...    for lvl3 in lvl2.itervalues()
...    for v in lvl3.itervalues()]
['123', '456', '789', '444']
>>> list(flatten_dicts(mult_dict))
['123', '456', '789', '444']
```